# Eigen, get inverse failed, and inverse() is so slow

Tags: eigen

I want to get inverse matrix, so here is the code:

```
if (m.rows() == m.fullPivLu().rank())
{
    res = m.inverse();
}
```

The dimension of `m` and `res` are all 5000 times 5000. And When I run the code on a high performance computing machine(Linux, [Tianhe 2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tianhe-2) SuperComputer), the process was kill at `res = m.inverse();`, and there was no core file or dump information generated. The console return `killed` and the process exited.

But there is nothing wrong on my Ubuntu laptop.

And the `inverse()`'s performance is poor and it costs a lot time.

So, why `inverse()` was killed on the high performance machine? Thank you!

Comment: What kind of performance are you getting? What are you expecting? Don't forget, inverse is O(n^3). What kind of message/dump/something are you getting from a computer that most of us won't have access to?

Comment: @AviGinsburg, it was very slow while getting the inverse. There was no core file or dump information generated. The console return killed and the process exited.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Full-pivoting LU is known to be very slow, regardless of its implementation.

Better use `PartialPivLU`, which benefits from high performance matrix-matrix operations. Then to get the best of Eigen, use the 3.3-beta2 release and compile with both FMA (`-mfma`) and OpenMP (e.g., `-fopenmp`) supports, and don't forget to enable compiler optimizations `-O3`. This operation should not take more than a few seconds.

Finally, do you really need to explicitly compute the inverse? If you only apply it to some vectors or matrices (i.e., A^-1 * B or B * A^-1) then better apply the inverse in factorized form rather than explicitly computing it. With Eigen 3.3:

```
MatrixXd A = ...;
PartialPivLU<MatrixXd> lu(A);
x = lu.inverse() * b; // solve Ax=b, same as x = lu.solve(b);
x = b * lu.inverse(); // solve xA=b
```

In these expressions, the inverse is **not** explicitly computed!

Comment: thank you, ggael. I need to get the inverse of a matrix. Can you post docs on compile optimization of Eigen?